# Dynamo Db with Latest data

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am having parition key as id that is VIN(vehicle identification number) sort key as timestamp, I want to execute query and want to know the latest record having the maximum timestamp(only single record based on vin with latest timestamp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Query` API with `ScanIndexForward` as false and `Limit` equal to 1 to achieve the result.

- ScanIndexForward = false -> means arranging the sort key in descending
  order
- Limit = 1 -> means return only one item

**Sample code:-**

```
var params = {
    TableName : "yourtablename",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#VIN = :vinvalue",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#VIN": "VIN"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":vinvalue":"somevinvalue"
    },
    ScanIndexForward : false,
    Limit : 1
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(" -", item.year + ": " + item.title);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public EventLogEntity fetch(String vin) {

                EventLogEntity eventLogEntityResult = null;
                EventLogEntity entity = new EventLogEntity();
                entity.setId(vin);
                DynamoDBQueryExpression<EventLogEntity> queryExpression =
     new DynamoDBQueryExpression<EventLogEntity>().withHashKeyValues(entity); 

//DynamoDBQueryExpression Works only for Partition, Sort and Indexes in Dynamo Db

                queryExpression.setScanIndexForward(false); // Will give you  result in descending order
                queryExpression.withLimit(1);// Will always give you single record
                List<EventLogEntity> result = dynamoDBMapper.queryPage(EventLogEntity.class, queryExpression).getResults();

                if (result != null && !result.isEmpty()) {
                    eventLogEntityResult = result.get(0);
                }
                return eventLogEntityResult;
            }
```